# sonarqube is stopped and elastic search

Tags: sonarqube

2023.10.04 17:28:21 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\SONAR\soanr 1\sonarqube-10.2.1.78527\temp
2023.10.04 17:28:21 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:56358]
2023.10.04 17:28:21 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [C:\SONAR\soanr 1\sonarqube-10.2.1.78527\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-17-jre\bin\java -Xms4m -Xmx64m -XX:+UseSerialGC -Dcli.name=server -Dcli.script=./bin/elasticsearch -Dcli.libs=lib/tools/server-cli -Des.path.home=C:\SONAR\soanr 1\sonarqube-10.2.1.78527\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\SONAR\soanr 1\sonarqube-10.2.1.78527\temp\conf\es -Des.distribution.type=tar -cp C:\SONAR\soanr 1\sonarqube-10.2.1.78527\elasticsearch\lib*;C:\SONAR\soanr 1\sonarqube-10.2.1.78527\elasticsearch\lib\cli-launcher* org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher
2023.10.04 17:28:21 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2023.10.04 17:28:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2023.10.04 17:28:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[WEB_SERVER] from [C:\SONAR\soanr 1\sonarqube-10.2.1.78527]: C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-17-jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\SONAR\soanr 1\sonarqube-10.2.1.78527\temp -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dcom.redhat.fips=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/sonar-application-10.2.1.78527.jar;C:\SONAR\soanr 1\sonarqube-10.2.1.78527\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-2.1.214.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\SONAR\soanr 1\sonarqube-10.2.1.78527\temp\sq-process10920120129165867553properties
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager (file:/C:/SONAR/soanr%201/sonarqube-10.2.1.78527/lib/sonar-application-10.2.1.78527.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
2023.10.04 17:28:25 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[Web Server] is stopped
2023.10.04 17:28:25 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
2023.10.04 17:28:25 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped

how to resolve issue? for sonar server up

Comment: Please format this so it can be read. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, make sure this is programming-related and not off-topic here.